# Monodroid OnDismiss with Dialog Fragment

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom `DialogFragment` which is called from a Fragment Activity which uses a `ListView`.

In API 14, it works fine. The `NotifyDataSetChanged()` is called when the Save button is pressed in the fragment and then it is dismissed.

In API 8, however, the following error is thrown after our 'Save' button is pressed in the fragment and it returns to the main activity.

*"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131099672, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class timepilot.EmployeesAdapter)]"*

I can use a workaround by writing an `Update()` method in the parent activity that simply calls `NotfiyDataSetChange()` and calling it in the fragment when Save is pressed and before `Dismiss()`, and that works fine, but it feels like a less correct way of going about this.

Is there anyway to implement an OnDimissListener for a Dialog Fragment using monodroid? (I have seen many examples in doing this with android, but cannot figure it out with monodroid).

The even more curious thing is that this error is not thrown in API 14, just in API 8.

EmployeeActivity.cs

```
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set up Listview
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.EmployeeMaster);
        employeesAdapter = new EmployeesAdapter(this);
        listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.employees);
        listView.Adapter = employeesAdapter;

        // Dedicate Buttons
        this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_edit).Click += EditButton_Click;
        this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_add).Click += AddButton_Click;
        this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_settings).Click += SettingsButton_Click;

        // Gestures
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
        listView.SetOnTouchListener(this);

        var x = employeesAdapter.Count;
    }

void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FragmentTransaction trans = this.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        UserProfileFragment userProfileDialog = new UserProfileFragment();
        userProfileDialog.Show(trans, "profile");          
    }
}
...
```

UserProfileFragment.cs

```
...
protected void Save()
    {
        String Name = this.Name.Text;
        String Number = this.Number.Text;
        EmployeeManagement.GetInstance().AddEmployee(Name, Number, true);
        EmployeeActivity activity = (EmployeeActivity)this.Activity;
        //activity.Update();
        Dismiss();
    }
...
```